# ReSharper: VS (2008 Team) takes focus from ReSharper -> ReSharper windows dissapear

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resharper

Seems I’ve got a problem with ReSharper in Visual Studio Team System 2008. When I try to open for example “Refactor this…” or “Go to type” or other ReSharper overlay-windows (if that is what it’s called) the ReSharper window just blinks for a small second and goes away. When I open the ReSharper “Rename”-form, both the “Rename”-form and Visual Studio blinks frenetically.

This kind of behavior indicates that VS is taking (or trying to take in the latter description) focus from ReSharper – which is also what JetBrains told me when I contacted them yesterday. Their support-guy told me to try the just released ReSharper 6.0 claiming that this issue had been solved. However the issue still remains. I’ve also uninstalled other VS add-ins like various RedGate products (ANTS Profiler etc.), StyleCop for ReSharper and Office Communicator – with no luck. I’ve tried to disconnect from the Team Foundation Server – same result. In desperation I reinstalled Visual Studio Team System 2008 and ReSharper 6.0, but it still behaves in the same manner.

Anyone seen this, or a similar, issue before and have a solution for it?

Thanks

-a-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My name's Alex, and I'm that "support-guy" you've been talking with.

As I've described to you earlier, this issue is not very common for our users, however there were several complains about this behavior.

This exact behavior is looking like there's a "focus steal" from the popup window (like, "Go To Type") similar to a simple mouse-click in the editor area of VS.
This issue as hardly reproducible for us since we haven't recieved any repro steps for this and failed to reproduce it on our own.

I was having a conversation with another customer, who had a similar issue with ReSharper 5.1. Ih his case, the cause of the issue was some kind of a mouse-driver installed in the system. He removed this driver and the issue has gone away.

This is the 1st time we receive this issue happened with ReSharper 6, that's why I've suggested to try it out.
As I've said to you earlier, I would recommend to investigate the software installed in the system, which can interference with a mouse/keyboard/window layout. This could be keyboard loggers, mouse drivers, and even AntiVirus/Security software. I assume this issue can't be reproduced on a clean OS/VS/R# installation.

We apologize for the inconvenience.
Please feel free to contact me via our Support Email if you have any questions and/or additional information.

Thank you.

Alex Berezoutsky

Support Engineer

JetBrains, Inc.

http://www.jetbrains.com

"Develop with pleasure!"

Answer (score 0):

I have also had this issue for a number of weeks but today had to uninstall `Visual Studio Team System 2008 Database Edition GDR R2` due to an unrelated problem. After re-installing this component, the loss-of-focus problem seems to be resolved!